# How to update content of files in SQL FILESTREAM and save it again?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlfilestream

I know how to insert, open and update NEW files such as Excel-files or Word-docs in SQL-Filestream.

But how can I open a file from filestream, edit the Content and save it back to Filestream without saving the retrieved data as a new file on harddisk.

Thanks yr help.

Michael

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it is SQL Server 2008 R2.
Additionally, the filestream file is opened from Access VBA.

Meanwhile, my idea is to open the file, save it on harddisk under a certain Name, let the user make its updates and Import the file after saving again to filestream and then delete the temp file from hardisk.

Or is there any better way to do so?